# jquery animate opacity not working cross browser

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser, opacity

I know this question has been asked but the answer is always that animate() handles cross browser differences between opacity:0 and filter:alpha(opacity=0)   not so in this case...

**I have this div**

```
.entry
{
opacity:0.4;
filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

**and this jquery**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('.entry').animate({opacity:'1'},700);
    },1000);
});
</script>
```

the text remains invisible alpha(opacity=0)  in I.E, works in chrome and firefox
can view at [sample domain](http://www.freeenergymedia.com).

**edit**
I have tried quoting and unquoting opacity:'1' does not help

fadeIn() not an option because i need to keep the div the same height and I can not change the CSS too much to keep the same height because it messes up my accordion menu.

thanks this is what ended up working x browser

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.entry').css({'opacity':0, 'filter':'alpha(opacity=0)'});
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('.entry').animate({opacity:'1'},700);
    },1000);
});
</script>
```

not sure why you have to use quotes around `'opacity':0, 'filter':'alpha(opacity=0)'` like this but that's the only way it worked.

also I had to put it after a different jquery highlight effect i had on an id# element.  when it was placed before that function in my header it kept that one from working.  maybe something to do with the css() function?

Comment: Could you try with `$('.entry').fadeIn(700);`?

Comment: unquote the '1'. That might be the culprit.

Comment: Instead of setting the initial opacity of `.entry` with CSS, let jQuery handle that too.  jQuery does an excellent job with opacity issues when you use it right.

Comment: I have tried quoting and unquoting opacity:'1' does not help

fadeIn() not an option because i need to keep the div the same height and I can not change the CSS too much to keep the same height because it messes up my accordion menu.

Comment: I know this is not what you ask (and I hate when people suggest things outside a question's scope) but... Is this anything a good old PNG with opacity could solve?

Comment: @ecchymose:  PNG is static; he's doing an animation and a transparent PNG introduces PNG transparency issues with certain versions of IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For code consistency and elimination of cross-browser issues, also set your initial opacity with jQuery instead of CSS...

```
<style>
    .entry {
    }
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.entry').css({opacity: 0.4});
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('.entry').animate({opacity: 1},700);
    },1000);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is going to work in older IE  versions, but it works in IE 7 mode on IE9...

Filter:alpha(opacity=#) is 0-100 for IE, so setting it to 1 may just be setting it to ... 1, when you want it as 100.

I just tried making this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N6GBU/1/, and the div text fades in (on IE9 anyway)... I just added filter to the animate. I'm not sure if this is what you were after exactly though...